Ensuring casts are applied before Laravel data constructor is called
I am attempting to make use of the laravel-data package from Spatie, in order to ensure a typed contract between different layers of my application. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with casting strings to an Enum, which according to the documentation should come out of the box...

It is possible to create a data object from a model... ...A model can have casts, these casts will be called before a data object is created.

Documentation link
However, it doesn't appear to be doing as per the manual, because the only way I can convert my model to a data object, when the model contains an enum, is to access the property prior to instantiating the data object.
Here is the Enum, (eloquent) Model class and Data class (separate files)
enum CarType: string
{
  case Sedan = "Sedan";
  case SUV = "SUV";
  ...
}
class Car extends Model
{
  protected function casts(): array
  {
    return ['type' => CarType::class];
  }
}
class CarData extends Data
{
  public function __construct(
    public CarType $type,
    ...
  ) {}
}

When I try to convert a Model object (retrieved from the database) directly to a Data object, I get

app\Data\CarData::__construct(): Argument #1 ($type) must be of type app\Enums\CarType, string given, called in /var/www/vendor/spatie/laravel-data/src/Resolvers/DataFromArrayResolver.php on line 95

However, if I access the type attribute on the Model, and then try and then try to create the DataObject, it works as expected. Example:
$car = Car::find(1);
var_dump($car->type); // Errors without this line
$car_data = CarData::from($car);
var_dump($car_data);

The other way I can get this to work, without artificially accessing the type property, is to bring all the code into a single file.
I can see a few possibilities here:

I'm misreading the documentation
There's a bug in the laravel-data package
There's a configuration option I can use to ensure that the casts are made immediately upon creating the Model, so that it's in a good state to create the Data Object.

I think the last is the most likely scenario - is anybody able to offer any advice here?
